# jQuery load AJAX content in <div> with $_GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, load

Let's say I list a list of rows with a link like this:

**content.php**

```
/*DATABASE CONNECTION AND SQL STUFF*/

<div id='content'>

  <?php 

    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT id, somedata FROM myTable");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

    echo "<a href='?p=moreData&id=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $somedata . "</a><br />\n";

    }

  ?>

</div>
```

**moreData.php**

```
<?php

  $id = $_GET['id'];

  /* SQL STUFF */

  echo "More information about" . " ". $somedata. " " . "wich has an id of" . " " . $id;
```

How can I use the `moreData.php` to be loaded with $_GET information inside a new div called `<div id='ajaxContent'>` in the file `content.php` instead of loading a new page?

I've read some about jQuery load but i'm very new to jQuery coding and I cannot figure it out by myself...

Comment: try reading this: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: Don't try reading anything on w3schools. It is home of many security holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preset an javascript var rowId with the id you want to sent via GET to moreData.php. I would set it as rel attribute to the tag and fetch it when I handle the click event.

```
echo "<a class='ajaxCall' rel='" . $row['id'] . "' href='?p=moreData&id=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $somedata . "</a><br />\n";
```

and then the click event

```
$('a.ajaxCall').click(function() {
  var rowId = $(this).attr('rel');
});
```

and in the same event the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: '/moreData.php', // your uri to the moredata
  data: { id: rowId },
  success: function(data) { // data is the response of the ajax call
    $('#ajaxContent').html(data);
  }
});
```

You need jQuery library.

Comment: Thank you. Could you present me with some code on how to do that?

Comment: It still opens in a new page but thank's anyway for that set of code. I guess it should get me started. (I have the latest jQuery library).

Comment: I'm still not able to make it work. It does not load the content in the div, instead it opens the link in a new page, like it did before. I guess it has something to do with my paging system. I use $p = $_GET['p'];switch($p){case "moredata":$p = "page/moredata.php"; break; etc... together with include ($p) on my content.php file... Any ideas?

Comment: @David do you still have problems with this ?